# How to preview a joomla article on the web (as it will be shown on the web)?

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, articles, article-manager

It's a very basic question, but I can't find the answer. JCE editor offer only a preview that will be shown in the editor, but I don't see any button that would simply open the (saved) article in the web.

I'm currently playing with the article IDs to open them on the web but I'm wondering if there is a quickest way.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there no inbuilt feature for that. But there is a plugin for that from Nonumber called "[Better preview](http://www.nonumber.nl/betterpreview)". It also allow to preview unpublished article (not in a new browser tab but in a back-end popup window).

EDIT: its quite buggy on multi-language website (path issue)